# How to remove items on Windows 7 start menu

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Is it possible to remove one of the  items on the right side of the Windows 7 start menu? The one with Music, Pictures, Games, Control Panel.

If it's not possible, how do I customize the game icon that shows up when I put my mouse cursor over the Games label?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by right clicking on the Task Bar and choosing properties.

Go to the Start Menu tab.

Customize

Scroll down to Games and select "Don't display this item"

I'm assuming you wanted to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

Right clicking the items on the right hand side (namely Documents, Pictures, Music, etc) and selecting "Don't show in navigation pane" seems to work.

Comment: try to right click on the game(which I want to remove).

Answer (score 1):

Open your registry and find or create the key below.

Create a new DWORD value, or modify the existing value, called "NoStartMenuMyMusic" and set it according to the value data below.

Exit your registry; you may need to restart or log out of Windows for the change to take effect.

```
Registry Editor Example
|   Name    Type    Data    |
|       (Default)   REG_SZ  (value not set) |
|       NoStartMenuMyMusic  REG_DWORD   0x00000001 (1)  |
-
|   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\... |
-
Registry Settings
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoStartMenuMyMusic
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (0 = default, 1 = remove folder)
```